# Guitar chord ear training website/software

Tags: guitar, chords, ear-training

As part of the justinguitar beginners guitar course, there are lessons where you have to guess which guitar chord is being played. This is all pre recorded though, so the lessons are always the same.

Is there any website or software that plays a random guitar chord for you to guess?

I'm aware of things like Theta music trainer and GNU Solfege, but I'm looking for something geared toward specific guitar chords.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you'll find what you need on [this site](http://www.chordpractice.com/).

In general, I think it is better to recognize **the kind of chord** (i.e. major, minor, 7th etc.) than **which chord**. The first can be used all the time. The second is more for folks who happen to have [absolute pitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_pitch).

Second: it is also very handy to learn to recognize the **function** of the chord. Is it the root chord, fourth, fifth. That way, it will be much easier to work out a chord progression from a recording.

Answer (score 1):

This one does scales and chords:

[www.good-ear.com](http://www.good-ear.com)

Answer (score 0):

The Guitar Ear Trainer at www.guitareartrainer.com does what you are asking.
You play the game with a real guitar - Chords, Chord Progressions, Melodies, etc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://chordify.net
Most of the cases its appropriate :-)
Happy Strumming!